# "Connection reset" exception when sending a callout (HTTP.send())

Tags: apex, callout, exception, httprequest, http

We have been receiving this intermittent exception when trying to make a callout for a few months now ("Connection reset" is the exception message):

> Connection reset Class.Sip_HttpUtil.callout: line 198, column 1   Class.Sip_AmenityController.getAwardMiles: line 697, column 1

It was a once a week occurrence for a while but now it's happening 3-5 times a day. It can happen anywhere we have a callout, not just the above area of code. If the user tries to callout again it most likely will come back successful. The request itself doesn't seem to be the issue. The line that throws the exception is the line sending the request:

```
res = http.send(req);
```

We have our callout wrapped in a try/catch block and "Connection reset" is the error message.

Does anyone know why this exception occurs? Is there a solution to preventing these exceptions? I searched Google already, found nothing helpful.

Comment: Is that your entire error message? Can you paste the message verbatim? It would also help to indicate the exception type.

Comment: Is this a "Callout Exception: IO Exception"? In my org, those usually come as read timeouts. For us, it's always a remote system problem, and I'd think a connection reset would be too. Do you have something like a load balancer or another proxy in front of your integrated system?

Comment: The "Connection reset" is the exception.getMessage(). Unfortunately we do not have any debug logs for this. I was just wondering if I could get any more information using just the exception message. I will have to find out how we can debug  this issue considering it happens randomly.